# ¿Como logro imprimir el Codigo QR en el HTML?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de facturación, el cual le estoy incluyendo el codigo QR para que me arroje el detalle de la factura, pero estoy trabajando con AJAX y no se como hacer para enviar el Codigo QR por medio de el y que me imprima el QR asociado al correlativo de esa factura. Tengo el Codigo PHP que me genera el QR, el cual funciona bien, me genera el fichero en PNG y lo aloja en el directorio, pero al momento de visualizar la factura o procesar la venta, lo crea m´ás no lo muestra en el HTML, he indagado en varios foros y recogiendo respuestas pero no consigo aún nada que me ayude, al parecer no es muy común desarrollar codigos QR en AJAX o no sé. Les remito el código:

```
GenerarQR.php

    <?php   

       
    //*Conexion a base de datos *//

    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ventas"); 

    $codigosqr = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT nofactura, fecha, usuario, codcliente, totalfactura, estatus FROM factura ORDER BY nofactura DESC LIMIT 1");
    
    $response = array();   
    
    //*Generando el codigo QR *//
    require 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php';

    $directorio = '';

    //*Si no existe la carpeta *//

    $filename = $directorio.'test.png';   
    

    //*El bucle y el envio del correo *//

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($codigosqr))
   {    
         
    $filename = $directorio. "".$row['nofactura'].'.png';

    $archivo = $filename;      
    
    $contenido = "No° Factura: {$row['nofactura']}, Fecha de Emisión: {$row['fecha']}, Vendedor/a:{$row['usuario']}, Su Codigo Cliente: {$row['codcliente']}, Total: {$row['totalfactura']}, Estatus de la Factura: {$row['estatus']}";
       
    QRCode::png($contenido, $filename);

    echo '<img src ="'.$directorio.basename($filename).'"/><hr/>';

    echo $archivo;    

    $response = array();   
  
            
     
    }
    
  ?>
```

La función que hice en AJAX en el archivo de functions.js (Se que tiene errores, y cuando le doy procesar venta, la consola solo me trae un echo de la ruta del png, lo cual me indica que lo creo en el directorio, pero no hago nada con eso porque lo que realmente quiero es que me imprima ese codigo en la factura), claro, si escaneo el codigo si me trae lo que se quiere, por alli estamos bien.

```
function GenerarQR(correlativo)

{


var id_detalle = correlativo;

$.ajax({

url:'GenerarQR.php',

type:'POST',

data: {id_detalle:id_detalle},


success: function(response) {


$(".CodigoQR").html(response);


console.log(response);

},



});

}
```

En el PHP donde se encuentra el HTML de la plantilla de la factura, hice esto:

```
<div class = "CodigoQR">


<img src="../test.png">

</div>
```

Declare la clase CodigoQR la cual llamo en el ajax para que me imprima ese codigo que genera según su correlativo, pero no me funciono. Les agradeceria muchisimo su apoyo ya que mi sistema esta 95% listo, solo me falta esto. Gracias!!!

Comment: ¿Para qué usas ```$directorio```? ya que veo que lo inicias a **$directorio = '';** pero luego nunca coge algún valor, y luego en cambio lo usas varias veces, por ejemplo aquí: ```echo '<img src ="'.$directorio.basename($filename).'"/><hr/>';``` también lo usas en tu ```$filename```

Comment: Yo declare esa variable para alojar el PNG en la carpeta local.

Comment: Personalmente no he usado esa librería de QR, pero según entiendo eso funciona, lo que no logras digamos es actualizarlo / obtener el QR que generas y actualizarlo en tu HTML. Luego otra cosa, la función ```GenerarQR(correlativo)```, ¿correlativo lo usas para obtener la factura asociado? pero no veo en tu **SELECT** que hagas algún ```WHERE correlativo = X``` para obtener sus datos correspondientes.

Comment: Voy hacerlo de la siguiente manera, voy a alojar la ruta del QR generado en la base de datos y despues paso los datos por ajax

Comment: Porque me estoy complicando más de la cuenta haciendo y haciendo.

Comment: Personalemente hago algo parecido, pero con codigo captcha, y tampaco es tan dificil, y funciona bien, yo uso JS, realmente es parecido al que tienes, te podria dejar un ejemplo. Mi duda respecto a lo que te comente antes el dato que le estas pasando (**correlativo**), seria digamos el nofactura, en tu sentencia?

Comment: Seria bueno....

Comment: Pero explicame como estas filtrando tu factura desde la BD, porque veo que pasas ```id_detalle:id_detalle``` pero en generar **GenerarQR.php** no lo usas en tu sentencia?

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un posible ejemplo. He comentado el código en si.

Manual: [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript)

**GenerarQR**

```
/**
  * Generar nuevo Código QR
  *
  * @param correlativo   (id_detalle)
 */
function GenerarQR(correlativo) {
                
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onload = function() {
      // Mostramos el codigo QR
      document.querySelector('.CodigoQR').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }

    /* Datos que enviamos por POST */
    const requestData = `id_detalle=${correlativo}`;

    xhttp.open("POST", "GenerarQR.php");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    xhttp.send(requestData); 
}
```

Luego para llamar a crear tu código QR, haces esto:
`GenerarQR(correlativo)`

Veamos el lado del PHP, he usado [sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php), que son más seguras antes posibles ataques de inyección SQL.

**GenerarQR.php**

```
// El metodo POST esta definido
if (isset($_POST)) :

    // Obtenemos el valor que le pasas a tu funcion para obtener la factura correspondiente
    $id_detalle = $_POST['id_detalle'] ?? '';

    // id_detalle es verdadero
    if ($id_detalle) :

        // Conexion a base de datos 
        $conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "ventas");

        /* comprobar la conexión */
        if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
            printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $conexion->connect_error);
            exit();
        }

        // Query (Esta parte corrigela como la necesitas)
        $query = 'SELECT `nofactura`, `fecha`, `usuario`, `codcliente`, `totalfactura`, `estatus` 
                    FROM `factura` 
                   WHERE `nofactura` = ?
        ';
        // Sentenica preparada
        $sentencia = $conexion->prepare($query);
        // Ligar parámetros para marcadores 
        //
        // i significa que id_detalle es un entero, si es cadena cambialo por s
        $sentencia->bind_param('i',$id_detalle); // Si no quieres usar el WHERE en tu query, esta linea la debes comentar o eliminar.
        // Ejecutar
        $sentencia->execute();
        // Transfiere un conjunto de resultados de la última consulta
        $sentencia->store_result();
        // Existe registros
        if ($sentencia->num_rows > 0) :

            // Ligar variables de resultado
            $sentencia->bind_result($nofactura, $fecha, $usuario, $codcliente, $totalfactura, $estatus);
            // Obtener valores
            if ($sentencia->fetch()) :

                // Creas tu codigo QR, si deseas la podrias tambien guardar en la BD, para asi tener relacion con el en un futuro. 
                //
                //
                // Generando el codigo QR 
                require 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php';

                $directorio = '';                

                $filename = $directorio . "" . $nofactura . '.png';
                                     
                $contenido = "No° Factura: {$nofactura}, Fecha de Emisión: {$fecha}, Vendedor/a:{$usuario}, Su Codigo Cliente: {$codcliente}, Total: {$totalfactura}, Estatus de la Factura: {$estatus}";
                   
                QRCode::png($contenido, $filename);
                // Imprimes tu codigo QR
                //
                // Podrias probar con un imagen JPG si no te funcionara, para ver que si funciona.
                echo '<img src ="' . $directorio . basename($filename) . '" /><hr />';

                //echo "<img src ='tu_imagen.jpg' alt='' /><hr />";

            endif;
        else :
            // No existe registros
            echo 'No existen registros en la BD';
        endif;
    else:
       echo 'Problemas con ID';
    endif;
else :
  echo 'El metodo POST no existe';
endif;
```

y en tu HTML

```
<div class="CodigoQR">Aquí mostrara el código QR cada vez que llamas a la función</div>
```